# Query to get records matching another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2008, I have abc and xyz table

abc

```
abc_id  | xyz_id1 | xyz_id2
---------------------------
 1     |  foo123  |  foo125
 2     |  foo127  |  foo129
```

xyz table

```
xyzid      | abc_id | location   | sequence_id
------------------------------------------
foo123     |  1     | park       | 1
foo124     |  1       mall       | 2
foo125     |  1     | park       | 3
foo127     |  2     | restaurant | 1
foo128     |  2     | lake       | 2
... -- several xyz records for order 2
foo130     |  2     | mall       | 5
```

I need to get all the abc_id where its xyz_id1's location is equal to xyz_id2's location. (park == park). xyz_id1 and xyz_id2 will always be the min and max sequence number in xyz table, so there'll probably make use of max(sequence_id) somewhere in the query.

In this example, it would return '1'. (this would  return many records, not just a scalar value).

My code has some business logic I'd rather not share. Could someone provide some assistance? I'm pretty sure I need some subquery or temporary table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT abc_id
FROM abc
INNER JOIN xyz1 ON abc.xyz_id1=xyz1.xyzid
INNER JOIN xyz2 ON abc.xyz_id2=xyz2.xyzid
WHERE xyz1.location=xyz2.location
```

This way you avoid the GROUPING.

Comment: Why would avoiding the GROUPING and Joining twice be an asset? (Not saying it wouldn't be - without looking at the plans I'm not sure which would perform better)

Comment: @Martin: Such query on a properly indexed table would be 10-30 times slower using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` than another join.

Comment: +1 I was quite sceptical about this as I thought `xyz.xyzid IN (abc.xyz_id1, abc.xyz_id2)` would be converted to 2 index seeks. I've just done a test and it wasn't. The plan for this is indeed a lot better.

Comment: @Martin: it's basically 2 hash joins (that are VERY fast) vs. nested loop (that is pretty slow) and an aggregate function. In ideal circumstances the `GROUPING` version can have similar performance, but it almost never happens. Based on pgAnalyser the `GROUPING` query can be upto 40x slower (I was a bit off there).

Comment: Not sure why you are using pgAnalyser. The OP is on SQL Server. The transformation rules available will presumably be quite a lot different.

Comment: @Martin: pgAnalyser (IMHO) looks better and has some features I like. The important parts look pretty much the same on all the engines I have for this type of query.

Answer (score 0):

Join the table twice, once for each `xyz_id`:

```
select  *
from    abc
join    xyz as xyz1
on      xyz1.xyzid = abc.xyz_id1
join    xyz as xyz2
on      xyz2.xyzid = abc.xyz_id2
where   xyz1.location = xyz2.location
        and xyz1.location = 'park'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT abc_id FROM abc a1 INNER JOIN xyz x1 ON a1.xyz_id1 = x1.xyzid INNER JOIN xyz x2 ON a1.xyz_id1 = x2.xyzid WHERE x1.location = x2.location
```